# Using headless browser in Coypu

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, coypu

I've heen recently using Coypu (https://github.com/featurist/coypu) for some web pages automation and it's great for that, if you need UI. But I wonder if I could do it on a headless browser, afaik Copyu supports only GUI browsers out of the box and I dont see any options to set headless mode.

Is it possible with default browsers or should I add some by myself (for example PhantomJS), and how could I do that?